# Group by not used not contained in aggregate function or group by clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to group by errorType but keep getting this error.
Column 'fid_crm_sp_recon.URL' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT URL, Name, statusCode, ErrorType
FROM fid_crm_sp_recon
GROUP BY ErrorType
```

Comment: Well, the error says it all. You are trying to group by one column, but selecting multiple different columns. So, what value should your query return for those (possibly duplicated) columns?, the `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc. You either group by all of them, or use an aggregation function on them

Comment: My guess is that your using Oracle as your DBMS? If so, you can only use aggregate functions (`SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.) in your select statement as well as the columns your grouping on. Other DMS'es (like MySQL) will happily accept this, but Oracle doesn't. What do you actually want to show? You are not using the group by in your select statement.

Comment: @ErikSchierboom Actually, MySQL is the only one that I know of that accepts this. No others that I know of do, primarily because it's not ISO-SQL compliant.

Comment: I would assume SQL Server based on the OP's other questions.

Comment: I am trying to create a table with all of those fields. And group them by errortype.

Comment: grouped by count of error type

Comment: Please show an example of your desired output, and possibly some table definitions and example data.

Comment: I was just told to show URL NAME and status code and group by error type. I am confused myself on what the desired output would look like. otherwise i would be able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're simply not setting up your `group by` correctly.  Here are just a couple of possibilities to get you on the right path:

```
-- Group by all columns
SELECT URL, Name, statusCode, ErrorType
FROM fid_crm_sp_recon
GROUP BY URL, Name, statusCode, ErrorType;

-- Run aggregates on the non-grouped columns
SELECT MIN(URL) AS MinURL
    , MAX(Name) AS MaxName
    , AVG(statusCode) AS AvgStatusCode -- Assuming a number here, just an example
    , ErrorType
    , COUNT(*) AS Num
FROM fid_crm_sp_recon
GROUP BY ErrorType;
```

Answer (score 0):

group by should always be used with aggregate function after `select` clause or apply group by to all selected columns

```
 SELECT URL, Name, statusCode, ErrorType  FROM fid_crm_sp_recon  GROUP BY URL, Name, statusCode, ErrorType
```

you can go through these links

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp